# Implementing forward declarations for functions in Python

Tags: python, c, function

Is it possible to declare functions and implement them separately in python ?
I mean something like in C :

```
void foo();



void foo() 
{

}
```

Comment: Why would you need to? Python functions are *first class objects*, their names *just names like any other*. You can set the name to `None` at first, but because Python looks up global names **at runtime** you don't need to.

Comment: No, it is not possible.

Comment: Are you looking for _forward declarations_? Those aren't needed in Python.

Comment: @ozgur: it is *possible* but not needed. The equivalent would be to use `foo = None`. Or `foo = lambda *args, **kw: None`. But the syntax in C is used for a problem that **doesn't exist in Python**.

Comment: But first `foo` being set to `None` doesn't imply anything about the next `foo` being set to a function. So I think, it is a bit different than the case we have here.

Comment: I am learning Python after a while of programming in c / c++ , and it is nicer to read . what about class functions ? Do I have to implement those in the class declaration as well ?  @MartijnPieters

Comment: @ozgur: nope. And `foo` being bound to a function doesn't mean you cannot later replace that binding with something else. Or delete it. In Python *it doesn't matter*.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I'd thought it like "declare the method signature now" and synthesize its body in some other place, similar to what `@dynamic` does in objective-c.

Comment: @Noam: they are still resolved dynamically at runtime. Are you getting any actual errors here?

Comment: @ozgur: In C? Yes. In Python? Names are bound to objects. Functions are just one type of object that happen to be callable. It doesn't matter what their signature is at that point. You can create other callable types too (just give your class a `__call__` method).

Comment: I am not getting any errors , it works . I was just looking for a more "readable" way to write functions and classes . thanks @MartijnPieters

Comment: @Noam: You said: "what about class functions?" You can define class methods outside the class, if you really want to. They can even be added to a class after you've already created some instances of it and the existing instances will "inherit" the new methods. It's also possible to add methods to individual instances, but that's a tiny bit more work. However, generally it's best to keep it simple and just define methods inside the class.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

C forward declarations are used to work around dependency problems. Function `foo` is used by function `bar`, and `foo` needs `bar` to exist before you can declare it:

```c
void bar()
{
    if (condition) { foo(); }
}

void foo() 
{
    if (condition) { bar(); }
}
```

won't compile because `foo` hasn't been declared yet; `void foo();` is the C spelling for *I know what I am doing, compiler, accept that `foo` will exist later*.

There are no such dependency problems in Python, as global names are looked up at runtime; they don't have to yet exist at compile time.

In other words, this *just works*:

```
def bar():
    if condition: foo()

def foo():
    if condition: bar()
```

because `bar` and `foo` are resolved at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

If your script is standalone you can use `__name__=='__main__'` to circumvent your problem with forward declaration [read more](https://docs.python.org/2/library/__main__.html).

Note that this is not really an answer to your question but a work around. 
Consider the following script as an example.

```
def main():
    bar()

def bar(): 
    print "Hello World"

if __name__=="__main__":
   main() # can be any function not necessarily "main"
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with `C`. Judging by the comments you've already gotten, seems like you're trying to solve a problem that doesn't exist in Python.

The closest thing I can think of for what you're asking is this:

```
def foo(): pass
```

This is used sometimes for testing purposes when laying out a class, for example, and you wish it to run smoothly even if you haven't written the code for a particular function yet.

However, there is another use for it. If you're trying to create the template method pattern, callback functions declared in the baseclass could take the following form :

```
def callback(): pass
```

These methods could then be implemented in subclasses (*optionally*), as opposed to abstract methods, which *must* be implemented.