# Python Functions AFTER code

Tags: python, function, prototype, definition

Is there a way (without putting the function in a separate file) to define the content of a function after the bulk of my code?  Sort of like C where you define prototypes and put the body later on in the file.

Ex;

```
blah blah blah
functionCall(arg)
blah blah blah

def functionCall(arg):
   blah blah blah
```

Comment: Why would you want that?

Comment: not really .... not sure why you would really want this though ...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does Python have class prototypes (or forward declarations)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/524714/does-python-have-class-prototypes-or-forward-declarations). It seems I've also might've linked the wrong thing, but this question has almost certainly been [asked before](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28514022/implementing-forward-declarations-for-functions-in-python).

Comment: It doesn't matter where in the file your function is defined, so long as it is defined before it is called.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. Instead of

```
blah blah blah
functionCall(arg)
blah blah blah

def functionCall(arg):
    blah blah blah
```

Do

```
def main():
    blah blah blah
    functionCall(arg)
    blah blah blah

def functionCall(arg):
    blah blah blah

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The `if __name__ == '__main__':` bit is mostly unrelated to the topic of the question; it just prevents the `main` from running if this file is imported as a module.